# NullPointerException when switch from stream to parallelStream

Tags: java, parallel-processing, nullpointerexception, java-stream

Help me understand this; I have a stream based logic that groups entities into a map-of-lists based on some key string that is constructed out of its fields.

Using stream this runs without any error:

```
Map<String, List<Entity>> mapOfkeyToListOfEntities = baseJournalEntries
.stream()
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(eneity -> buildKey(entity)));
```

But if I try to do this in parallel by changing the steam() method to parallelStream() like so:

```
Map<String, List<Entity>> mapOfkeyToListOfEntities = baseJournalEntries
.parallelStream()
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(entity -> buildKey(entity)));
```

I get an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.__newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java)
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
     at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:598)
     at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
     at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.invoke(ForkJoinTask.java:735)
     at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateParallel(ReduceOps.java:714)
     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:233)
     at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
```

Since the stream version works, all entities are able to generate a key, so there can't be a NPE in the buildKey... I don't get it. Where do I need to look?

Comment: I'm guessing there's a concurrency bug in `buildKey()`. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: en**E**ity -> buildKey(entity)

Comment: It may very well be a concurrency bug in buildKey, but the question then is how do I find that?

Comment: The stack trace you have posted represents the recreation of the exception in the caller thread. There should be another cause to this exception, the original exception whose stack trace will show you where the original exception happened.

Comment: But... Making buildKey synchronized should fix concurrency issues, right? (It is a private non static method.) It does not.

Comment: May fix or may not. It is impossible answer without sources of buildKey and functions which it calls. Can you give sources of class contains buildKey?

Comment: Why don’t know what `buildKey` does and why it fails. Making it `synchronized` ensures that it will not be invoked concurrently, but it may still fail if it assumes to be called with the stream element in a specific order.

Answer (score 1):

There indeed is a NullPointerException occuring in the buildKey method, but that exception is swallowed by the ForkJoin framework, or so it seems. It is totally not visible in the initial stacktrace; only by catching runtime exception in buildKey and printing it, I can make it visible. (The NPE itself is indeed caused by the code running on a different thread, which does not have some thread related data bound to it.)